# How to import private key using gpg2 during travis build?

Tags: java, travis-ci, root, sudo, gnupg

I'm trying to upgrade the Travis CI build for one of my projects to move from the "xenial" dist to the "bionic" dist, and I'm having trouble trying to import a signing key during the build due to differences in behavior in the gpg command.
The "xenial" dist includes gpg v1.4.20 and I used a command like this to import my signing key into the Travis build worker's local keyring:

```
gpg --import signing.key
```

The "bionic" dist now includes gpg v2.2.4, and the same command as above now fails because
gpg requires the passphrase to be specified.  I believe this new requirement is due to the gpg command being run as "root" within the Travis build.

I can reproduce this behavior using gpg v2.2.27 on a Fedora 34 machine. i.e. If I run gpg as non-root, the `gpg --import signing.key` command works fine and no passphrase is required, but if I run that same command as root, gpg displays a dialog in my shell asking me for the passphrase.

Is there any way for me to run gpg as root within my Travis build to import the signing key without needing to specify the passphrase?

This is part of a java project that uses maven to sign and deploy jars on Maven Central. How do others do this using gpg v2.x???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After more experimentation, I've found that the "--batch" option allows the import to succeed without having to specify the passphrase:

```
gpg --batch --import signing.key
```

I swear that I tried that option before asking my question above, but perhaps I inadvertently tried it in conjunction with other options :)